# How to create a fromNow field in Gatsby graphql

Tags: graphql, momentjs, gatsby

So I have a bunch of events. I want to show them in my Gatsby site as future events and past events. Buildtime, I need to figure out if the event is already past or still coming. So I wrote this function:

```
exports.setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType = ({ type }) => {
  if (type.name === `my_event_type`) {
    return {
      fromNow: {
        type: GraphQLBoolean,
        resolve: source => {
          const { raw_date } = source.fields;
          return moment().diff(raw_date, 'days') <= 0;
        },
      },
    };
  }

  // by default return empty object
  return {};
}
```

This works perfectly fine to figure out if the `raw_date` of my event has passed or not. *but*.... this field ends up in the cache... So next build run, this field will no be re-evaluated, so it is still true/false from the previous run. So it keeps showing me events from the cache time, not the build time.

Any idea's how to make sure this field gets re-evaluated during build or to use another function diffing a date?

Comment: Do you *need* to evaluate this at build time?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you will have to read _all_ events to the frontend to evaluate them runtime